# when I install or uninstall a package, a "extra" log will often show, why?

Tags: npm, package, installation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoyPv.png)

this is the img ,just click for detatil

`` D:\STUDY\React-Study\step-01>npm uninstall babel-p
reset-react-hmre --save-dev
- babel-preset-react-hmre@1.1.1 node_modules\babel
-preset-react-hmre
- babel-plugin-react-transform@2.0.2 node_modules\
babel-plugin-react-transform
- react-deep-force-update@1.0.1 node_modules\react
-deep-force-update
- react-proxy@1.1.8 node_modules\react-proxy
- react-transform-catch-errors@1.0.2 node_modules\
react-transform-catch-errors
- react-transform-hmr@1.0.4 node_modules\react-tra
nsform-hmr
step-01@1.0.0 D:\STUDY\React-Study\step-01
`-- react-hot-loader@3.0.0-beta.2
npm WARN step-01@1.0.0 No repository field. ``

I want to ask why appear `` `-- react-hot-loader@3.0.0-beta.2 ``

Comment: Please elaborate your question. How are you installing a package? What log? (And you know the only duty of logs is to record user actions. That's why we create logs, right?)

Comment: I have changed, thank you !

Comment: Great. (y). In SO you should always try to include maximum details of the question for members to quickly get the issue and help future visitors.